# htaccess rewrite laravel routes to lv.php and wordpress route to index.php

Tags: wordpress, laravel, .htaccess

I have configured wordpress site with laravel.

For configuration:
In `public` folder, I have created `wp` folder and kept all the wordpress files in it. I have renamed laravel `index.php` file to `lv.php` and kept the wordpress index.php file in public folder.

Now i want to route every wordpress routes from index.php and every laravel route from lv.php.

I want to run front-end site pages using wordpress like home page, feature and benefits.

I have used following htaccess file. It is rewriting some routes to laravel index file. I want to reverse it.

Can anyone help me about it.
Example URLS:
Wordpress:

https://example.com/

https://example.com/features

https://example.com/benefits

https://example.com/package

Laravel:

https://example.com/packages/plan/2

https://example.com/admin

https://example.com/login

https://example.com/client

```
# BEGIN WordPress
# The directives (lines) between "BEGIN WordPress" and "END WordPress" are
# dynamically generated, and should only be modified via WordPress filters.
# Any changes to the directives between these markers will be overwritten.
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(packages/plan|login|logout|admin|signin)(|\/) /lv.php [L]
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress`
```

Comment: Thank you for sharing your htaccess file in your question, could you please post samples/examples of urls which you want to redirect/rewrite too in your question for better understanding of your question, thank you.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13. Updated